# Finding operator norm of $Tx(t)=T(x_1,x_2,x_3)(t)=x_1+x_2t+x_3t^2$, with $X=\mathbb{R}^3$ with $l^1$ norm, and $Y=C[0,2]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question:

Let $X$ be the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $l^1$ norm and let $Y$ be $C[0,2]$ with the usual supremum norm. Define $T:X\to Y$ by:

$$Tx(t)=T(x_1,x_2,x_3)(t)=x_1+x_2t+x_3t^2$$

Find the operator norm of $T$.

---

Now I am a bit confused by this one... maybe I am overthinking it, but I'm not sure.

I know that by definition the operator norm of $T$ is:

$$\|T\|=sup\{\|Tx\|:\|x\|\leq 1\}$$

However I am confused how I would go about finding what the operator norm is in this situation (we have rarely directly defined specific operator norms, and we have never been tasked with finding one before). Some help and guidance with this one would be appreciated.

Comment: You're tasked to find the smallest constant $M>0$ such that $||T(x)|| \leq M ||x||$ for all $x$, now try to bound $||x_1 + x_2t + x_3t^2||_{\infty}$ What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Many problems of this kind can be solved in two steps (sometimes easy, sometimes really difficult):

1. Bound $\|Tx\|$ assuming that $\|x\|=1$ (or $\|x\|\le1$, it is equivalent). Minkowsky, Hölder and triangle inequalities are often used here.
2. Find an example of that the bound is achieved. Sometimes this is impossible because it is not achieved. In this case, prove that the bound can not be lowered.

In this particular problem you need to find the supremum of the set

$$\{x+yt+zt^2: 0\le t\le2, |x|+|y|+|z|= 1\}$$

But
$$|x+yt+zt^2|\le|x|+t|y|+t^2|z|\le|x|+2|y|+4|z|=1+|y|+3|z|$$

Since $|y|+|z|\le1$, $|z|\le1-|y|$, so last expresion is less than or equal to
$$1+|y|+3-3|y|$$
whose maximum is clearly $4$.

Can you find for which $x,y,z$ is $\|T(x,y,z)\|=4$?

Comment: Wouldn't there be an infinite amount of $x,y,z$ as $T(x,y,z)$ is still dependent on a 4th variable, $t$?